# Utilizing constraint to create a new table in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a query based off of the following information below. While attempting to create this, I keep violating the primary key.

```js
CREATE TABLE writers
    (authorid VARCHAR2(4), 
    lname VARCHAR2(10), 
    fname VARCHAR2(10), 
    isbn VARCHAR2(10), 
    title VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT title_nn NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT wt_pk PRIMARY KEY (authorid),
    CONSTRAINT wt_fk FOREIGN KEY (isbn) REFERENCES books (isbn)); 
INSERT INTO writers 
(SELECT authorid, fname, lname, isbn, title
     FROM author
     JOIN bookauthor USING (authorid)
     JOIN books USING (isbn));
ALTER TABLE employees
ADD CONSTRAINT et_pk
PRIMARY KEY (ssn);
```

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important information in the exercise you try to solve is: **do not copy the data from these tables**.

In your database schema, you have table `bookauthor` which represents many to many relationship between `book` and `author` tables. Each author can write more than one book and in these case statement used to populate **`writers`** table returns more than one row for the same authorid. This results with primary key violation during batch insert done by you.

You can check this by slightly altering your query to find `authorid` with more than one row in result

```
SELECT authorid, count(1)
     FROM author
     JOIN bookauthor USING (authorid)
     JOIN books USING (isbn)
GROUP BY authorid
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

**`writers`** table with primary key set to `authorid` is not very useful so that's why you should not try to populate it in this exercise.